# Burger Menu Stops working with Sass Bootstrap subtheme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, sass, drupal-8, hamburger-menu

Using Drupal 8, Bootstrap 3 theme, the burger menu appears fine once browser window scales small enough to display it,
however once I set my Bootstrap SASS subtheme as the default,
the burger menu disappears/stops working.
I've done little to no customisation yet so it is basically as per the starter kit content, copied into the main theme folder.
I can't track where the error is occurring to make this burger menu stop showing.

Comment: It's very difficult to offer any meaningful solutions without seeing your code and structure.  Without that no one can validate whether your claims of little-to-no-customization are accurate, if you have it configured correctly, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks 2pha,
I figured out what was happening: in the Structure / Block Layout
I had moved "Main navigation" into the "Navigation" block, instead of the "Navigation (collapsible)" block. Once I moved "Main Navigation" back into "Navigation (collapsible)" block, then the burger menu started appearing again.
I was trying to move Navigation for aesthetic reasons, but obviously this is not a good way to do it.